# How can I use Xpath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How can I use Xpath,

here my xpath is `id('product')/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td[2]`

I used in my selenium like this

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//id('product')/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td[2]")).getText();
```

But Iam getting error like `The given selector //id('product')/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td[2] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:`

Anybody can help me??

My HTML code is

```html
<table id="product" class="displaytable">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="hide sorted order1">PRODUCT_ID</th>
      <th class="hide">PRODUCT_NAME</th>
      <th class="hide">ACCESS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Cash</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="productAccess" value="1" checked="checked" id="p1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="__checkbox_productAccess" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Saving</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="productAccess" value="2" checked="checked" id="p2"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="__checkbox_productAccess" value="2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Recurring Deposit</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="productAccess" value="3" checked="checked" id="p3"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="__checkbox_productAccess" value="3" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Bank Loan</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="productAccess" value="4" checked="checked" id="p4"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="__checkbox_productAccess" value="4" />
      </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Recurring Deposit Saving</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="productAccess" value="5" checked="checked" id="p5"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="__checkbox_productAccess" value="5" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I clicked particular element and  I taken Xpath

Comment: Can you share the html code for the element for which you are looking for xpath?

Comment: I have added HTML code also,pls chek that one

Comment: There's no element with parameter `id`=`product` in the HTML you included. Please include which exact element from the DOM you'd like to select. Are you looking for the second column of the first row perhaps without any id=product?

Comment: Yes I am looking for the second colums of the all rows..here i taken xpath for second column of the first row ,its showing xpath is "id('product')/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td[2]"

Comment: If I use "driver.findElement(By.id("product")).getText()",iam getting all values like "1 Cash,2 Saving" but i want cash ,saving etc

Comment: Again, there are no such elements in the HTML you posted. Please provide the HTML you're testing against and add the **specific** result set you're expecting.

Comment: HI  gertvdijk,"id = product" is Table id

Comment: I have updated the HTML code,pls check

Comment: My requirements is check box only,but i am passing value from Excel sheet is "cash,saving",but in HTML they are mentioned as labol,how can i take that value,or other solution for check box

Answer (score 3):

Your xpath has an error, it should be: `//table[@id='product']`

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='product']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).getText()`